# How to get the last two digits of next year?

Tags: datetime, xstring

It seems I can't solve the problem by google. I want to get the last two digits of the next year. I googled that the two digits of this year can be get by `\Year{\the\year}`

```
\def\Year#1{\def\yy@##1##2##3##4;{##3##4}\expandafter\yy@#1;}
```

Then, I try to define the next year by counter

```
\newcounter{nyear}
\setcounter{nyear}{\the\year}
\addtocounter{nyear}{1}
```

the problem is that `\Year{\thenyear}` not work, I don't know why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generic version for getting the last two digits of any year specified with an offset with respect to the current date. *Caveat*: four digit year numbers are assumed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\lasttwoofyear}[1]{% #1 is the offset
  \expandafter\getlasttwo\number\numexpr\year+(#1)\relax\relax
}
\def\getlasttwo#1#2#3#4\relax{#3#4}

\begin{document}

\lasttwoofyear{0} (This year)

\lasttwoofyear{1} (Next year)

\lasttwoofyear{-18} (A few years ago)

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `expl3` (via `xparse`) so we don't have to rely the string we operate on has four items.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\lasttwoofyear}{m}
 {% #1 is the offset
  \egreg_lasttwo:f { \int_to_arabic:n { \c_sys_year_int + (#1) } }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \egreg_lasttwo:n
 {
  \tl_range:nnn { #1 } { -2 } { -1 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \egreg_lasttwo:n { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\lasttwoofyear{0} (This year)

\lasttwoofyear{1} (Next year)

\lasttwoofyear{-18} (A few years ago)

\end{document}
```

Comment: OP speaks about next year but because of your general routine, version 1) gives some small problems for `\lasttwoofyear{7982} (A few more years to ago)` it returns `000` ...

Comment: @albert That's why I added the second version. For the first one four digit year numbers are assumed.